# Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I'm getting this error

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'.
```

When running a build.  (likely because I'm on the Android simulator, and the JIT is catching it.)

I'm getting these warnings when building:

```
Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Mono.Android' not resolved
        For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}
        Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently
        For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}
        HintPath attribute not found
        For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}
        Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0, assembly named 'Mono.Android' not found.
        For searchpath {PkgConfig}
        Considered Mono.Android, but could not find in any pkg-config files.
        For searchpath {GAC}
        Considered Mono.Android, but could not find in the GAC.
        For searchpath {RawFileName}
```

I've installed both Mono for Android and MonoTouch on my mac.  Could this have over-written some settings?

I'm also getting these as warnings:

```
Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Found a conflict between : 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' and 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' reference.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Found a conflict between : 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' reference.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Found a conflict between : 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' and 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' reference.
```

I'm sure that there is just some setting under the project's compiler that I just don't know about.

Comment: Yes, the operator==() overload for the Type class is a .NET 4 feature.  You can't ignore those warnings.

Comment: I know, but I don't think I'm overloading it.  The code I'm using was taken from the 'Tasky' sample - which runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Not the point, the compiler was happy to emit the code to use the operator.  But then when the program ran, it didn't actually use a 4.0.0.0 assembly, it used a 2.0.5.0 assembly.  Which doesn't have the operator.  This is what the warnings told you would happen.  Why that happened, I have no idea but there's something screwed up in the build when you get warnings like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've somehow ended up building your Mono for Android project referencing 4.0 assemblies. In theory this should not be possible unless you edited the project file with a text editor (MonoDevelop will not allow you to modify the project so that this will happen).

I suggest you create a new Mono for Android project from a template, and compare the two project files to see if you can deduce what is wrong in yours.

Comment: I think I created the Solution as a "Blank C#" Solution, to which I added 2 Mono for Android projects.  I re-created the solution as a Mono for Android, and it worked fine.